# Write the norm $||R^h v||$ just in function of $v$ if $R=[ Q \, \mathbf{0}]$ and the columns of $Q$ form an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $Q$ be an $m \times (m-k)$ (complex) matrix where its columns form an orthonormal basis ($m-k$ vectors). We define matrix $R=[ Q \, \, \mathbf{0}]$, where $\mathbf{0}$ is the $m \times k$ zero matrix. Also, we define an $m$ dimensional (complex) vector $v$. Let $R^h$ be the hermitian transpose of $R$.

Can we write the norm $||R^h v||$ just in function of the coordinates of $v$?

Comment: What do you mean by a unitary matrix that is not square? There can be no such thing.

Comment: @AlexM. thank you for your remark. question edited.

Comment: I still do not agree: if $m-k$ vectors form a basis, then the space must have dimension $m-k$, therefore each vector should have $m-k$ components, not $m$ as they currently have.

Comment: @AlexM. The work is over $\mathbb{C}^m$, so each vector has $m$ components. The $m-k$ vectors can be seen as the basis of a subspace in $\mathbb{C}^m$. Hope I am clear now.